# Why isn't my pygame window not white and not staying open and quitting when I try to exit it?

Tags: python

```
import pygame
import time 
# WINDOW SETUP
window = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
time.sleep(5)

FPS = 60

# RGB VALUE VARIABLES 
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

def background(window): 
    window.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.update()

# FRAMERATE AND EVENT LOOP INITIALIZATION 
def main(): 
    run = True 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run: 
        clock.tick(FPS)
        background(window)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if running == False:
                pygame.quit()
```

Above, is my code. I'm trying to make a pong game with pygame. The text editor I am coding with is Visual Studios Code (VSCODE).

Comment: Do you call the `main()` function anywhere?

Comment: ohhhhh I didn't realize I didn't call the function. Such a careless mistake on my part. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to call the main. You should also make you're code nice and easy to read when possible. I imported `pygame as pg` which makes typing `pygame` functions a bit faster as you have less to type. Also, it's better to use global variables to hold variables that won't change through the program, like screen width, height, colours, etc. Then make sure you initialise the module.

As well as that, the only update you have is in `background()`. You should put the update at the bottom of the loop and remove it from `background()`. This way everything above will update each loop.

I apologise for not adding you're FPS counter in here as well but I think this should be enough to help you get you're window running with more readable code and a more efficient loop.

```
import pygame as pg

# Global Variables
screen_width = 900
screen_height = 500
screen = pg.display
window = screen.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
colour = 'red'


def main():
    # Initialise module
    pg.init()

    pg.display.set_caption('PONG')

    running = True

    while running:
        # This is a better way of writing your loop
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False

        # Call background function
        background()

        # Updates window
        # place this inside the loop near the bottom
        # so everything is updated at the end of each loop
        screen.flip()


def background():
    window.fill(colour)


# Remember to call your main function
# This if statement is good practise but not required
# You can just place main() here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```